# Chrome Extension: creating buttons in popup with user action

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

In my google chrome extension, I am trying to create buttons in the popup when a command is pressed. In the popup, I can display a message when there is no buttons, but when I try to add a button, the button does not appear.

I'm using `document.createElement("button")` and `document.getElementById().appendChild()` to create and append the button to a previous button.

## popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "popup.js"></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "buttons"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## popup.css

```
#button
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: lightblue;
    background-color: white;

    padding: 24px 32px 24px 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#button:hover
{
    background: url('/images/btndark.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    border: none;
    width:100%;
    min-height:25px;
}

#buttons
{
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

## popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
{
    /* checks and displays if storage is empty */
    chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(groups)
    {
        var totalGroups = groups.groupCount;

        /* no buttons to be displayed */
        if (totalGroups == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = "<b> Empty! </b>";
            document.getElementById("buttons").style.color = "grey";
        }
        /* creates the buttons */
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < totalGroups; i++)
            {
                getGroup(i);
            }
        }
    })
})

/* creates and adds the button to the list */
function getGroup(i)
{
    chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i, "tabName" + i, "tabUrl" + i, "tabCount" + i, "groupCount" + i], function(group)
    {
        var groupButton = document.createElement("button");
        groupButton.id = "btn" + i;   // button id
        groupButton.type = "button";
        groupButton.innerHTML = group['' + i];   // displays name of the button
        groupButton.name = "btn" + i;
        groupButton.title = group["groupName" + i];   // name of the button

        groupButton.onclick = openTabs(i, group);
        // put button in popup
        document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(groupButton);
    })
}

/* opens the group's tabs */
function openTabs(i, group)
{
    var id = this.id;
    id = id.replace("btn", '');

    // opens first tab as an active tab
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrl" + i][0], "active": true});
    /* opens the rest of the tabs */
    for (var j = 1; j < group["tabCount" + i]; j++)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrl" + i][j], "active": false});   // opens url of tab in the group
    }
}
```